# How to make this logic

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having a problem with this exercise
[image]

So far I have the boxes, but the logic in javascript I don't know how to do ? Any advise ?

this is my progress:

[image]

The code is really simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>David Aparicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box active">
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    </div>        
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button> Left </button>
    <button> Right </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any javascript to accomplish this? if so, please show us, and mention the part where you're getting stuck. That way you'll get better results in this community

Comment: No I'm stuck I don't know how to move to the each div

Comment: Basically you need to write a javascript code to interact with the elements and move the 'active' class. Hint: use arrays to model the list of boxes.

Comment: Well, break it down.  Get a reference to each div, then write the code to set the color of a div to white or red, then write the swap code.  We are happy to help you get your code working, but doing the entire thing is generally considered too broad.  You should spend some time learning the very basics of JS first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.

First I added ids to your buttons to reference them.

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="left"> Left </button>
  <button id="right"> Right </button>
</div>
```

Then my javascript looks like this:

```
//Find all boxes and put them in an array
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
let activeIndex = 0;

function changeActive() {
  //remove previous active class
  document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");

  //find box at active index and add active class
  document.querySelectorAll(".box")[activeIndex].classList.add("active");
}

//Event listeners to increment and decrement the active index

document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(activeIndex > 0) {
    activeIndex -= 1;
    changeActive();
  }
});

document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(activeIndex < boxes.length -1) {
    activeIndex += 1;
    changeActive();
  } 
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r6foyj1d/13/